# Why won't the variable show up in the Unity inspector even after making the variable public?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
{
    public float velocity;
    public Rigidbody2D birdRigidBody;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            birdRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up* velocity;
        }

    }
}
```

I want the variable `velocity` to show up in the unity inspector. I have tried to refresh the assets folder but it won't work. I'm new to this so have no clue what I'm doing.

[image]

new: [image]

Comment: Does your other variable (birdRigidBody) show up? Can you try placing a [SerializeField] attribute in front of the variable? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VariablesAndTheInspector.html

Comment: No I don't think that works either, it continues not to show up in the inspector. And birdRigidBody doesn't show up either.

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question

Comment: How did you create the C# file? Did you create it via Unity or did you add it through Visual Studio? I generally would also recommend following common C# naming conventions, i.e. file and class share the same name and both start with a capital letter (e.g. BirdFlight.cs and class name BirdFlight). Is your Script associated to a game object or prefab?

Comment: Did you check this already? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html

Comment: I created a new script through the inspector on the sprite, so I guess it is associated. I just reloaded Unity and it said that the script could not be loaded, and it says it has a compiler error.

Comment: I will try making a new script then associating it with the sprite after?

Comment: You removed the ```public``` keyword, that is required for serialization. Can you show the output? What is the compiler error that you see?

Comment: I genuinely have no idea, it says compiler error or something and won't let me run the game. I remade it then associated it with the sprite, but it still won't show up in the inspector. I can add a new screenshot?

Comment: Does it not give you any details in the output log?

Comment: Sorry, where is the output log?

Comment: I meant the console window: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Console.html

Comment: If it says theres a compiler error it hasn't compiled the code so until thats fixed it probably wont show

Comment: Nah it literally says nothing